# Alamofire request being fired more than once

Tags: swift, alamofire

Im currently using the code below to download an image from a URL (NSData of image is needed) but for some reason the request is fired more than once in some cases (Times 2 or 3 times), I was wondering if there was something I'm doing wrong here and will it have an impact on memory or slow down my app? (This is  implemented within a tableview cell, there is a condition set in place to not fire the request if the image within the current cell image already has an image which works a expected)

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, imgURL)
                .response{ response in

                        if let image = response.2{
                      print("GIF image downloaded") //FIRED MORE THAN ONCE (2-3)
                    }else{
                        print("GIF image download failed")
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Is `response.2` a typo?  That aside, could you post the code of where you call this from the cell?

Comment: @nebs its not a typo, just an unnamed tuple and will do